# OpenCV CvCamera Preview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opencv, avfoundation

I am new in OpenCV as well as AVFoundation framework , I am trying to show the Video Preview captured from camera without writing it into a file. But when **start** button is pressed i need to write the video in to Document Folder . Here is the piece of code that i am trying to execute but when it runs it does not show any video Preview. Please help me.

```
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 15;
    self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
    self.videoCamera.recordVideo = YES;
    [self.videoCamera start];
    [self.videoCamera.captureSession stopRunning];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the video preview from the AVCaptureSession and add it to a view(layer) in your application.

Here "session" is the AVCaptureSession that the camera is connected to and "self.videoPreviewView" is a UIView in my application that is used to display the video preview.

```
// Get the preview for the session
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *videoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

// Set the frame and add the previewLayer as a sublayer in the UI
CALayer *viewLayer = self.videoPreviewView.layer;
videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.videoPreviewView.bounds;
[self.videoPreviewView.layer addSublayer:videoPreviewLayer];
```